# Android Remote (WiFi) debugging native app doesn't work

Tags: android, android-ndk, adb, lldb, android-debug

I have a native (Java with NDK C++ code) Android app that when connected **over usb** I can run in Debug mode within Android Studio and set break points etc fine.

I am debugging a USB host app - so having the usb connected is not an option. So I would like to run my apps in debug mode over wifi within android studio. My build configuration sets "debuggable" to true.

I connect over wifi as follows:

```
adb kill-server
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.0.xx:5555
```

**This gives me logcat output over WiFi OK - so is not a connection issue**

However when I go to run my app in Debug mode from Android Studio:

1. the app is launched on the device (so must have connection), and display showing "Waiting For Debugger" is shown.
2. The debug console in android studio lists:

```
    05/21 17:18:47: Launching 'app' on Google Pixel 3a.
    $ adb shell am start -n "com.myapplication.testapp/com.myapplication.testapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
    Waiting for application to come online: com.myapplication.testapp | com.myapplication.testapp.test
    Waiting for application to come online: com.myapplication.testapp | com.myapplication.testapp.test
    Connecting to com.myapplication.testapp
    Waiting for application to start debug server
    Waiting for application to come online: com.myapplication.testapp | com.myapplication.testapp.test
    Connecting to com.myapplication.testapp
    Now Launching Native Debug Session
    $ adb shell cat /data/local/tmp/lldb-server | run-as com.myapplication.testapp sh -c 'cat > /data/data/com.myapplication.testapp/lldb/bin/lldb-server && chmod 700 /data/data/com.myapplication.testapp/lldb/bin/lldb-server'
    $ adb shell cat /data/local/tmp/start_lldb_server.sh | run-as com.myapplication.testapp sh -c 'cat > /data/data/com.myapplication.testapp/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh && chmod 700 /data/data/com.myapplication.testapp/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh'
    Starting LLDB server: /data/data/com.myapplication.testapp/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh /data/data/com.myapplication.testapp/lldb unix-abstract /com.myapplication.testapp-0 platform-1590077930063.sock "lldb process:gdb-remote packets"
```

3. The bottom of Android studio there is a loading wheel, with messages - goes something like this:

```
1. Starting LLDB server
2. Attaching to the app
3. Loaded module:LLModule(path=C:/...this file changes - it appears to be loading several files)
4. Resuming the app process
5. Loaded module:LLModule(path=C:/
```

4. After this, the debugger console goes blank, and the app starts to run as normal. BUT breakpoints are not hit, and I can't pause the app, as I can normally when connected over usb.

I've also tried using the "attach debugger to android process" option in Android Studio - the process appears in the list presented when the button is pressed, but its unable to attach - after some time the debugger console displays:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

I wonder if its something to do with the localhost:8600 - should this be pointing at the ip address of the phone? I can't find an option to change this though.

Any ideas of what I can try to fix this? Having proper debug capabilities would massively help my work right now!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happened to me today. After many trials, I found it works after I change the encryption protocol to WPA-PSK in the wifi AP settings section of my router's admin panel.
It worked for me. But I think you also have to check out whether the debugger server
is listening at localhost:8600

By the way, if the adb is always timed out due to your apk being too large or the wifi too slow, this build.gradle configuration might be somewhat helpful:

```
android {
    
    adbOptions {
        timeOutInMs 30 * 1000
    }
....
}
```

Good luck!